# Inertia Django Vite not working on deployment

Tags: django, deployment, vite, inertiajs

I'm trying to deploy this template to fly.io (https://github.com/mujahidfa/inertia-django-vite-vue-minimal.git). Additionally I installed "gunicorn" as WSGI-server.

I got it running locally but if I deploy it, I get a CORS-error because Vite ist still requesting localhost. All I see is a white page.

index.html:

```
{% load django_vite %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  {% vite_hmr_client %}
  {% vite_asset 'main.ts' %}

  <title>Inertia + Django + Vite + Vue minimal</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% block inertia %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

In the browser it gets resolved to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/@vite/client"></script>
  <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/main.ts"></script>

  <title>Inertia + Django + Vite + Vue minimal</title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="app" data-page="{&quot;component&quot;: &quot;Index&quot;, &quot;props&quot;: {&quot;name&quot;: &quot;World&quot;}, &quot;url&quot;: &quot;http://nameless-mountain-1344.fly.dev/&quot;, &quot;version&quot;: &quot;1.0&quot;}"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I think the interesting parts are:

```
{% vite_hmr_client %}
{% vite_asset 'main.ts' %}
```

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/main.ts"></script>
```

Has anybody an idea how to get it working? I couldn't figure it out for days now.

I've tried fiddling with the Dockerfile, but I'm still in the eary phase with fullstack-developement.

Also in the vite.config.ts I've tried many things but nothing seems to work.

Help is pretty much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @dejmedus I could deploy the template successfully. But in my main project

```
{% vite_hmr_client %}
{% vite_asset 'main.ts' %}
```

still gets resolved to

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/static/main.ts"></script>
```

and I can't figure out where the error is.

**UPDATE 2**

Finally I found the error: It didn't work because I had set DEBUG=True on the server and for some reason the scripts refer to localhost in this case. If I set DEBUG to False it works just fine. Now I just have to find out why this is happening...

**SOLUTION**

DJANGO_VITE_DEV_MODE was set to True. Therefor `{% vite_hmr_client %}` and `{% vite_asset 'main.ts' %}` was included and reffered to localhost. I've set it to False and everything worked as expected (Thanks @dejmedus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned the template and followed [this Fly.io tutorial](https://fly.io/blog/deploying-django-to-production/) to deploy it, have a look through and see if it can fix the issue.

The only change in the dockerfile was replacing demo.wsgi with <name_of_the_project>.wsgi. I didn't need to touch the vite.config.

Edit: Debug should be set to false in production, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#debug). However, this particular problem seems to be explained [in the django-vite repo the template uses](https://github.com/MrBin99/django-vite#template-tags)

Important bit: “{% vite_hmr_client %} will add a  tag to include the ViteJS HMR client. This tag will include this script only if DJANGO_VITE_DEV_MODE is true, otherwise this will do nothing.”  DJANGO_VITE_DEV_MODE is set to DEBUG value in settings.py.

Comment: Thanks to your repo I got it working too. So the starter-template works but my main project based on this template still has the problem. Now I just have to figure out where my project breaks.